# Redirecting missing staging images to production

Tags: nginx, redirect, amazon-s3

I currently have a production web site which hosts a large volume 50GB+ of images on s3.  For my staging environment at first I was cloning the production bucket into a staging bucket but this has become too large to maintain.

The changes that occur on staging must continue to be isolated to the staging environment and not touch production.

What are the best options for redirecting missing staging assets to production?  I have seen this article which is an example: http://containerdiv.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/safely-using-production-assets-in-staging/

This is rails + unicorn + nginx + S3.

Comment: Can you be more specific about 'changes that occur in staging must be isolated'?  Do you have a specific location {} block for your assets?

Comment: paperclip is used.  https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.  each environment has its own options.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you worry about the [`if`](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil) directive. If so, you can use [`try_files`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#try_files) instead, something like this:

```
    location ~* \.(jpe?g|gif|png)$ {
        try_files $uri @missing;
    }
    location @missing {
        rewrite ^/(.*) http://production.yoursite.com/$1 permanent;
        break;
    }
```

Comment: While try_files is a good option it doesn't really solve my issues.  With this setup how can I see changes I made to staging as the assets aren't local, they are on a staging bucket?